# Syntax MySql Insert Error

Tags: java, mysql, syntax

I got a Sql syntax error`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
            You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '8 , 0' at line 1`,(i take attribute by input),my table in mysql is,for example i post an insert:

INSERT INTO `itshop`.`supply` (`id`, `idSupplier`, `dateTime`, `quantity`, `totalCost`) VALUES ('2', '4', '2009-1-4', '24', '245');

```
int rs2 = st2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO supply VALUES ( "
                                    + id + " , " + idSupplier + " , "
                                    + dateTime + " , " + idProduct + " ,"
                                    + Quantity + " , " + price + "");

                    if (rs2 == 1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Sale,
                                "Product Ordered", "Supply",
                                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
                    }
```

Comment: And what is the actual error? MySQL tells you _where_ it fails in the query.

Comment: You need to add right parenthesis `)` in SQL query.

Comment: This is completely unsafe, is opens up the possibility of SQL injection. Sue prepared statements or escape every argument / value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the varchar types within `''` like this

```
int rs2 = st2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO supply VALUES ( '"
                                    + id + " ',' " + idSupplier + "' , '"
                                    + dateTime + " ', '" + idProduct + " ','"
                                    + Quantity + " ', '" + price + "'");
```

Use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of Statement and this removes the confusion of `'`

Simple example

```
PreparedStatement pt=connection.prepareStatement(insert into test values(?,?));
pt.setString(1,"hi");
pt.setInt(2,1);
pt.executeUpdate();
```

For your insert operation PreparedStatemet will be

```
PreparedStatement pt=connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO supply VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)")
pt.setString(1,id );
pt.setString(2,idSupplier );
pt.setString(3,dateTime );
pt.setString(4,idProduct );
pt.setString(5,Quantity );
pt.setString(6,price );
int rs2=pt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: the attribute datetime is a type DateTime in sql ,with java i use this as a string for example string date="2014-03-02", is a good practice?

Comment: @CiMat no this is not a good practice.If it datetime then you should also use in date object in java.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the apostrophes `'` in the String which represents your INSERT statement. Also, you need to add the right bracket `)`. You don't have them. Even better, use a `PreparedStatement` as this way of creating `INSERT` statements (by using direct concatenation of the values) is a bad practice.